# Loading WMF is failing, yet converting a PNG to WMF succeeds but loss of background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, wmf

Working with the RichTextBox, I gave up on trying to make a PNG have a transparent background, and I really don't like the code from Microsoft that in order to convert an image object to wmf, that you must write two files, then read it back in to the memory stream, so I cracked open Illustrator, and converted one emote to WMF so it is allegedly in the format that RTF requires.

Enclosed are the images in the formats I am trying :

- WMF [big-smile.wmf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00896825120262658520) (had to link this as SO doesn't allow upload of WMF)
- PNG [image: big-smile.png]

The trouble I am having right now, is that the following code, results in no image being displayed:

```
public string GetImage( string file, int width, int height ) {
    float dpiX;
    float dpiY;
    string rtfimage;

    using ( Graphics g= this.CreateGraphics() ) {
        dpiX=g.DpiX;
        dpiY=g.DpiY;
    }

    using ( MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream() ) {
        byte[] data=File.ReadAllBytes( file );
        ms.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
        rtfimage=@"{\pict\wmetafile8\picw"+(int)( ( (float)width/dpiX )*2540 )
                            +@"\pich"+(int)( ( (float)height/dpiY )*2540 )
                            +@"\picwgoal"+(int)( ( (float)width/dpiX )*1440 )
                            +@"\pichgoal"+(int)( ( (float)height/dpiY )*1440 )
                            +" "
                    +BitConverter.ToString( ms.ToArray() ).Replace( "-", "" ).ToLower()
                            +"}";
    }
    return rtfimage;
}
```

While the following code works (but only with non-wmf files) :

```
public static string GetEmbedImageString( Image image ) {
    Metafile metafile=null;
    float dpiX;
    float dpiY;

    using ( Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage( image ) ) {
        IntPtr hDC=g.GetHdc();
        metafile=new Metafile( hDC, EmfType.EmfOnly );
        g.ReleaseHdc( hDC );
    }

    using ( Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage( metafile ) ) {
        g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.DrawImage( image, 0, 0 );
        g.Clear( Color.White );
        dpiX=g.DpiX;
        dpiY=g.DpiY;
    }

    IntPtr _hEmf=metafile.GetHenhmetafile();
    uint _bufferSize=GdipEmfToWmfBits( _hEmf, 0, null, MM_ANISOTROPIC,
    EmfToWmfBitsFlags.EmfToWmfBitsFlagsDefault );
    byte[] _buffer=new byte[_bufferSize];
    GdipEmfToWmfBits( _hEmf, _bufferSize, _buffer, MM_ANISOTROPIC,
                                EmfToWmfBitsFlags.EmfToWmfBitsFlagsDefault );
    IntPtr hmf=SetMetaFileBitsEx( _bufferSize, _buffer );
    string tempfile=Path.GetTempFileName();
    CopyMetaFile( hmf, tempfile );
    DeleteMetaFile( hmf );
    DeleteEnhMetaFile( _hEmf );

    var stream=new MemoryStream();
    byte[] data=File.ReadAllBytes( tempfile );
    //File.Delete (tempfile);
    int count=data.Length;
    stream.Write( data, 0, count );

    string proto=@"{\pict\wmetafile8\picw"+(int)( ( (float)image.Width/dpiX )*2540 )
                      +@"\pich"+(int)( ( (float)image.Height/dpiY )*2540 )
                      +@"\picwgoal"+(int)( ( (float)image.Width/dpiX )*1440 )
                      +@"\pichgoal"+(int)( ( (float)image.Height/dpiY )*1440 )
                      +" "
                      +BitConverter.ToString( stream.ToArray() ).Replace( "-", "" )
                      +"}";

    return proto;
}
```

They both return the appropriate string format for embedding a wmf file in a RichTextBox control as follows

```
{\pict\wmetafile8\picw[WIDTH]\pich[HEIGHT]\picwgoal[WIDTH (twips)]\pichgoal[HEIGHT (twips)] [HEX BYTE ARRAY OF FILE]}
```

I am looking for a way to get the appropriate string value for this *that works* with the **WinForms RichTextBox** component.

I do feel this is a VERY specific question relating to a very specific problem and have given more than enough code and details in order for you to duplicate the problem.  Ideally, if you have experienced this issue and have found a work-around that does not involve messing with the users clipboard (I am aware of the copy/paste method which is not only much slower, but it interferes with the users clipboard.  I am also aware of the work-around the clipboard issue which stores the old clipboard data in memory and sets it back, however this is not without flaw in some cases the data can not be set back).

I am not looking for the easy road, although you would think by 2015, that the RichTextBox control in WinForms would have evolved during the 10 years in .NET.

I also realize, that the other option is to use WPF which opens Pandora's box to all the other problems (as well as benefits) of using WPF.  I prefer to stick with the language that is overall much more mature.

What I need help with, is very specific: I posted another thread referencing something else regarding this matter, but it was closed under the claim that it was not specific.  This is the same question, with many MANY more details, in the hopes that you will see how specific this is.

C# > WinForms > RichTextBox > Replace String with Image which requires the format to be very specific and in WMF as a very specific byte string with very specific formatting tags as a string > Problem getting the images to load properly in the format required while maintaining transparency or at least using a definable color if can't keep transparency on vector.

Comment: In the future if you struggle to get an answer to a question, don't forget you can add a bounty - you have plenty of rep to do so!

Comment: halfer - I was aware, thank you.  Reserving any 'bounty' for when I have rep in the 10's of thousands.  The question is valid, but if no one has a solution, that is fine as well -- eventually someone may.  As you may have noticed, I am very patient when it comes to some things regardless of the duration.  If no one has an answer, thats fine, neither do I. I did find another solution to do something similar by building my own html rendering engine and displaying the content like that -- ironically, this was faster than waiting on a solution to this dated tech.

Comment: @halfer - the other notes which you removed, were to add the requisite 'clarity' as the 'other' thread which bore the same level of consideration and condensing of information, was very clear, and concise, but was closed to being unclear.  This is a very complex issue, so I felt it was more lack of understanding from the closer that was the major contributing factor to the closure, so an invitation to explain anything they find that lacked clarity was a necessity when authoring this question. It really can not be simplified any further.

Comment: I guess whether a note adds clarity is a subjective thing. My rule of thumb is that if a lot of material talks about the question itself ("meta" chat) rather than the technical problem itself, then it does not do much to shed light on the actual problem. If you find you wish to ask a question in future, please try to amend it rather than create another one - a closed question can be reopened.

Comment: @halfer - of course.  tbh, I forget what the original question was, but I do recall vaguely that it was further up the scope and VERY specific about the issue. In simple terms, it could be evaluated to  "why is ABCD different than WYXZ?", and then being cited / closed for not being specific when in fact, there was no further it could go to be specific.  The above question in turn, was on the same project, but a different approach to the same issue which had (as you can see from the Q) interesting results.